# Is it possible to divide chaincode in multiple files by taking advantage of module system in Go?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I currently have my chaincode in a single file and it's getting bigger as I am adding more functions, so it's really frustrating to maintain it.

I thought it's good idea to take advantage of module system in Go, But I can't figure out the way.

What I have:

```
my_chaincode
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── chaincode.go (whole chaincode)
```

AND

```
my_chaincode
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── modules
│   └── smartcontract.go  (All other functions)
└── chaincode.go          (Only main function)
```

What I want:

```
my_chaincode
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── modules
│   ├── admin.go   (Some functions)
│   ├── system.go  (Some functions)
│   └── user.go    (Some functions)
└── chaincode.go   (Only main function)
```

(*Note: I have a basic knowledge of creating and using Go modules.)

I tried dividing the chaincode (like What I want) and deployed the chaincode, but when I try to execute a transaction the chaincode container crashes with error -

`status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction`

This doesn't happen with my previous two attempts.
I am sure that I am lacking some knowledge regarding Go modules.

What am I missing?
Some reference like a GitHub repository with structure like what I want will be great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible using Go modules.**

Let me explain using a example, consider file structure like below

```
my_chaincode        (not necessary to use modules as folder name)
├── go.mod          (created after executing `go mod init`)
├── go.sum          (created after executing `go mod tidy`)
├── modules         (not necessary to use modules as folder name)
│   ├── module1.go  (Some functions)
│   ├── module2.go  (Some functions)
│   └── module3.go  (Some functions)
└── main.go         (not necessary to use "main" as file name)
```

- create folder "my_chaincode"
- `cd my_chaincode`
- `go mod init my_chaincode`

```golang
// main.go

package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi"

    "my_chaincode/modules"  // importing all files from modules folder
)

func main() {
    chaincode, err := contractapi.NewChaincode(new(modules.SmartContract))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error create chaincode: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }
    if err := chaincode.Start(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error starting chaincode: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

```golang
// modules/module1.go

package modules

type SmartContract struct {
    contractapi.Contract
}

type User struct {
    // anything
}

func (s *SmartContract) InitLedger(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface) error {
    // your logic
}
```

```golang
// modules/module2.go

package modules

import (
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi"
)

// private function (because name starts with a small letter)
func validateUid (uid string) (bool, error) {
    // your logic
}

// public function (because name starts with a capital letter)
func (s *SmartContract) Create_User (ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, uid string, name string, age int) error {
    // your logic
    // you can use "validateUid(uid)" function here
}
```

```golang
// modules/module3.go

import (
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi"
)

func (s *SmartContract) Create_Record (ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, rid int, uid int) error {
    // your logic

    // you can use "validateUid(uid)" function here
    // you can use "User" struct here
    // you can use "ctx.Create_User(uid, 'user1', '20')" function here

    // all above uses may seem irrelevant, but my intention is to show
    // that you can directly use them without again defining in this file, 
    // which is the main goal. So, the whole chaincode can be divided 
    // into small modules.
}
```

- `go mod tidy`
- `GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor` - (optional, if you know what it does)